# TinyOS: converting uint16_t and uint8_t into uint32_t

Tags: tinyos, type-conversion

I'm having the following problem:

I have an `uint8_t  h_MSB` and `uint16_t h_LSB` and `iwant` to combine them into a `uint32_t`

So here is my code:

```
void  parseHeader(MyPackage Header,uint32_t* timeStamp ){
(*timeStamp) = (Header->h_MSB <<16)| Header->h_LSB;
}
```

But it does not seem to work;

I tried it with `h_MSB = 10` and `h_LSB= 10`

I get 10 for the timestamp.

The problem seems to be that if I shift beyon `7 bit` all information from
`h_MSB` ist lost, but how can it be since timestamp is a `uint32_t` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `h_MSB` is `uint8_t` and the shift operation is performed within the `uint8_t` type (or possibly within `uint16_t`, but it doesn't matter), so you get `0`. Cast it to `uint32_t` before shifting:

```
(*timeStamp) = (((uint32_t)Header->h_MSB) << 16) | Header->h_LSB;
```